# Using Postman flows, how do I extract json data from a send request block response and pass that data to another send request block?

Tags: json, postman, postman-flows

I have this test postman flow.  The "Send Request" blocks call the postman echo API.
[image: Postman flow]

Here is the query I'm using on the postman echo API.
[image]

As a test, I want to grab the value of ParamKey1 from the response of the 1st "Send Request" block, and set that as the value for ParamKey2 for the 2nd "Send Request" block. So the terminal should output something that looks like:

```
    --- [11:10:62]
data:
  status: '200'
  body:
    args:
      ParamKey1: ParamValue1
      ParamKey2: ParamValue1
    headers:
      x-forwarded-proto: https
      x-forwarded-port: '443'
      host: www.postman-echo.com
      x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-635c1747-3f6540ef480363162df797d5
      headerkey1: HeaderValue1
      accept: application/json
      content-type: application/json
      user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
      cache-control: no-cache
      postman-token: 65e322d6-0902-409e-aa33-06708fd968d7
      accept-encoding: 'gzip, deflate, br'
      cookie: >-
        sails.sid=s%3A9xptL5itn2oEwj4NxkYfXoSsDgS13YWi.iaAtzHY1w0Eruqz%2FE%2FqNvWXBCveZAxR%2BTexowwOnjF0
    url: 'https://www.postman-echo.com/get?ParamKey1=ParamValue1&ParamKey2=OK'
  headers:
    Date: 'Fri, 28 Oct 2022 17:54:15 GMT'
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: '640'
    Connection: keep-alive
    ETag: W/"280-JzDhIiJr9HLb7DpmhfeDR5s/2T8"
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    set-cookie: >-
      sails.sid=s%3AmRRu0ezsQK6_4JXiBy0AwjwJdt9sep8j.fe%2F%2Blx4Fx6wtY5MFUpSkdJQ3JqJFoUFM9MaohQeuLkc;
      Path=/; HttpOnly
  http:
    statusCode: 200
    statusMessage: OK
    responseTime: 253
'@durable': {}
```

Right now it only give me the option to get the body as a String as shown below:
[image: 2nd Send Request block]

How can I get what I described above to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

In Request 2, you can input directly the path into `Current Value`, choose type `ref` and ignore the warning.

[image]

**Solution 2:**

- From Request 1, you save response as example.

[image]

- In Request 2, choose path_to_value you want to get

[image]